# Fetch name / value pairs from the page url

Tags: javascript, html, url

I have a page here:

http://recipehappy.com/share.php?user=Mains&PID=2&passkey=bmAjWDMwmWcOBLoU4B0q2NARCG0PBTc1

I need to get the PID value and passkey value into JavaScript variable on the page. This may be simple, but I'm blocked.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

ex: `getParameterByName('PID')`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/643761